# Python regex to match a quoted string

Tags: python, regex, quotes

Really sorry about posting a regex question.
Here it is :

I'm trying to match an URL containing a quote, contained in a LIST, like so :

```
urls = ["my.url.com/Som'Link"]
```

I match it with another list, that only contains the last word of the URL, like so :

```
match_list = ["Som'Link"]
```

I test like this :

```
p = match_list[0] + "$" #(I need the $ to make sure the word is the last of the URL)
s = urls[0]
if re.search(p, s):
    #Use that link in some way.
```

I am completely unable to find a way to make it match.
I tried :

```
p = r"" + match_list[0] + "$"
```

no luck.

```
p = compile(r"" + match_list[0] + "$")
```

no more luck.

*Note : I tried those two lines with **re.escape** arround my match_list[0] too...* **Doesn't work !!**

I hope my submission is OK. Just comment and I will improve it if necessary.

Comment: don't use regex. also: look at the difference between `re.match()` and `re.search()`!

Comment: 1) The others are right that your problem doesn't need regex. (2) Your example code worked fine for me: http://pastebin.com/vLqq1nSQ

Comment: sorry 'bout the match/search thing… i somehow thought you had used match

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex for this you can just test:

```
if "Som'Link" in urls[0]
```

This will test whether "Som'Link" occurs anywhere in the url.

Assuming your urls always end with the string you're trying to match the end only you can use `endswith`

Comment: If the urls stay of this form, but I used `in` if you want to test for matches for additions to the url.

Comment: Specifically `urls[0].endswith("Som'Link")`

Comment: Thanks! My error was also somewhere else btw... Useful method anyway :)

Comment: Can I "close" my topic ?